# Animate image ( left to right ) opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I've a task to move an image ( file.jpg ) from left to right side using openCV and python.

i've tried

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('C:/Python27/03323_HD.jpg')
cv2.imshow('ImageWindow',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

but its simply opening the image . instead of that just vibrate/shake animate image while opening .

Comment: @HarryPotfleur updated

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand we need to open piece-wise. While `imshow` only opens the whole image at one go, we can first chose a region of an image and then increase it slowly with time  and show it using `imshow`.

I am showing left to right, you can try other variants also.

```
import time
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image')
x,y,z = img.shape
for i in range(x):
    cv2.imshow(img[:i,:,:])
    time.sleep(100)#change the number of seconds
#imshow only opens the image
```